# When i enter castle valkihar I get attacked

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

This is really confusing to me I’m already a vampire lord and have freed serana I also have completed the bloodline Quest yet I can’t enter castle volkihar without getting attacked by everyone

Answer (score 3):

It's not entirely clear from your description at which point in Dawnguard's main story you are, however it sounds like you're either banished from the castle or not welcome yet.

In either case, my suggestion would be to try to push on in the main story for a bit. Helping the Volkihar clan should pretty quickly give you the reputation to roam the castle freely.

Comment: I was at the beginning of the quest line

Comment: @ShapeshyfterGaming Yeah, pushing on should do the trick then.

Answer (score -3):

I don't know if you have already got an answer for your question, but if you have attacked anybody in castle Volkihar they will attack you back.